# `java_home` utility in mac is unable to find newly installed amazon corretto 11 JDK

Tags: java, macos, java-11, corretto

`java_home utility` (/usr/libexec/java_home) in my Mac OSX is unable to list recently installed Amazon Corretto 11 GA.

Earlier I was using Corretto 11 RC version and it used to show up in java_home.

As you can see that I've following JDKs in my machine.

[image]

But `java_home` does not list amazon-corretto-11

[image]

Comment: Since there are multiple version of jdk installed on machine, what is output of `echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Comment: add following commands to .bashrc or .zshrc which ever shell you are using `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
 export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` more info: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/mac-configurations